# Scaling svg image to fit width - viewBox + preserveAspect ratio don't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, scale

I don't understand this.
I have an inline svg, as part of a sprite.

```
<symbol id="mysvgimage" viewBox="0 0 1083 703" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
 //...some more svg stuff in here
</symbol>
```

I use it here:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
          <svg style="width:100%;height:100%;"><use xlink:href="#mysvgimage" /></svg>
        </div>
```

However, It still ends up being tiny, with lots of whitespace around it. What am I doing wrong? I thought providing a viewbox in the svg + using preserve aspect ratio would do the job. But I seem to not have understood it completely.

My goal is to stretch the image to the size of the parent div, so I want to do `width:100%` and then height whatever fits the width (so I thought I could just do `height:auto`)